# If songbirds never existed what would replace them?

Tags: biology

Back home, the bird order Passeriformes consists of roughly 100 families totaling up to roughly 5400 species--that's over half of the entire class.

But if the songbird order never existed, how would this affect the overall class? Which order would fill what niche?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question.  Is there a way you can narrow it down to something less epic than finding replacements for 5400 species that just upped and quit one day.  Speaking of which, how did the songbirds dissapear?  If they never existed in the first place, those niches may simply not exist.  Evolution makes do with what it has.

Comment: @JohnWDailey, we need question titles to be meaningful.  If "cute" gets in the way of "clear", it has to lose out.  I've rolled back your rollback of another moderator's title edit.  Please try to be more careful with your titles.

Comment: They would be replace by songbats.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not biologist but I will give it a try.

The songs of these birds can sometimes be used by other animals, because it can point a danger out (birds sing to mate and to communicate, sometimes when facing a danger like a predator). But this is not the major role of these birds, and i really don't know if their absence would change anything on this point.

The biggest role of these birds is determined by

- What they eat : insects and seeds.

There are many species eating insects (other insects like dragonfly, spiders, reptiles...), and without songbirds, they would have more to eat and would prospere a little more. If not sufficient, there might be other insects-eating species. Carnivorous plants ? Other reptiles, mammals ? Pick what you want.

Fruits and berry-eating birds have another role : scatter the seeds. There must be species that eat fruits and seeds and then go away. But there are already other species doing that (rodents, and even bigger animals, like humans are eating seeds and berries...)

Except a few more spiders and rodents, I don't think there would be a big change here.

- What they are eaten by

It's a bigger issue as the predators did evolve exactly to chase songbirds. Some birds of prey (like accipiters) would not exist at all. There would probably be other predators species chasing the reptiles/insects/spiders... that took the place of song birds in the food chain. If they don't need to chase something that can fly, they don't need to fly. On the other hand, cats can chase songbirds when they find some, but if they don't they have mouses and rodents instead.

Some of the songbirds migrate, but I don't know wether it could change anything. But there are another birds migrating, not songbirds, then if they have a role in spreading plants/insects by changing continents, the job would still be done.

Conclusion : 
Without songbirds in the evolution, other species, known or not in our worls, would have taken their place. Nature keeps a good balance and would have evolved in another way. 
In fact (I would like a confirmation) for what I know and what I can find on the net, even if songbirds should disapear just know, nature could replace them with another species (it will take time), but it would kill their predators (mostly birds of prey as terrestrial predators could replace them with other small animals such as lizard or rodents).

Answer (score -1):

The sound of singing insects leading by the crickets may be replaced instead.
If no better one is there than these.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  As it stands this does not answer the question which is more related to the impact of birds in general if song birds didn't exist.  It takes time to get used to the format around here but your answer would probably be better left as a comment.  You will gain the ability to comment on questions and answers as you gain reputation.

Answer (score -2):

Songbirds are part of nature like other creatures.so,they will remain as they are, now,as long as we,the listeners of their songs live with them.
They will sing longer than what we expect to them.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.  You can edit an answer by clicking the "edit" link under it instead of adding a new answer and deleting the old one.  As with the other one, though, it's not clear how this answers the question.  We're looking for longer answers that explain why and how (and, of course, answer the question that was asked).  Please check out our short [tour].  Thanks.